# Midori - How to activate Shockwave Flash on startup

Tags: 12.10, midori

I love this little speedy browser, however, I do not always find it easy to configure.

For some reason Shockwave Flash extension would not stay activated on startup, as the Adblock extension does, which is slightly annoying. I'd prefer to combine it with a flashblock userscript rather than to go to the preferences everytime I want to use flash.
Do you know how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this answer comes a little too late, but it might help someone who googles about this issue.
I've recently installed elementary OS that comes with Midori as default browser. I first tried installing Ubuntu restricted extras:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

It worked with SOME youtube videos, but not the ones embedded on facebook. Also, when I tested flash player plugin (here: http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/), it said *"missing plugin"*.

Then, I added this line: *export MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins"* to configure Midori's flash path (*this is for elementary OS. Other distro might use another path)*

```
sudo nano /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
```

It still didn't work, so after googling a little more, found this script: https://gist.github.com/lewisgoddard/6223985, wich solved all the issues :D

*Note*: you might need to restart your browser for changes to take effect.